# Using a java library containing no class file

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I have downloaded a java library from github, but it only contains java Code files and no class files. I tried to compile it via eclipse, but it doesnt show me the files after the Import. 
How can I use this program although?

You find the repository here:
https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB

Comment: Link for github repo from where you downloaded that java library?

Comment: Check the GitHub repo's readme (if present) for build instructions.

Comment: The readme is not very informative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no binaries a supplied you should clone the project locally an run gradle or maven build to install in your local repo. Then add the dependency to your project